# Trying to clear a TextWatcher every time it detects a certain string and continue reading the EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have an EditText in which I want to be able to detect when the user types in a flagged word. When this word is detected, a button becomes visible and the user has more options. I have been able to do this with a TextWatcher. The problem is that I'm storing the flagged word that is used in an array every time it is detected by the Textwatcher. But once the word is in the EditText, every character that is entered afterward causes the flagged word to be entered into the array again since the flagged word is still in the EditText. I was wondering, is there any way to clear the TextWatcher so that once I find a flagged word, it starts watching only for what I type after that? The word variable in the code below is where the flagged word the program is checking for is stored.

```
    txtMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String tmp = s.toString().trim().toLowerCase();
            if (flagged == true) {
                CheckWords.setVisibility(0);
            }
            if (tmp.contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
                flagwordsused[i] = word;
                //txtPhoneNo.setText(""+tmp);

                i++;
                flagged = true;
            }

        }
    });
```

Any help you could give me would be appreciated. Maybe there is some completely different way of accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I just need to break the tmp string into substrings and see if the flag word is contained in one of the substrings instead of the entire EditText.